# SignalR .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr

I am evaluating SignalR for ASP.NET Core, the documentation for previous version of [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis) stated that

> SignalR scaleout with Redis does not support Redis clusters.

Would the new version of SignalR support this?

If support is not available for this, how would one go about ensuring high availability in the use case where you have multiple SignalR instances with a redis backplane?

Answer (score 0):

There are less requirements on the redis implementation in ASP.NET Core (like not requiring a monotonically increasing id), that said, we haven't tested with redis pubsub and redis cluster (which has scale issues anyways https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2672)

Comment: is this answer still accurate? There just seems to be a web of dodging answering the question as to whether Asp .Net Core SignalR supports Redis clustering, or what about a single master/slave replica?

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing with failover.  Master/slave configuration with a load balancer that does the healthcheck and failover.  I made my slave not readonly so that if it fails over it is still operational for writes (even if I can't get those back to the master)